# How to do a mouseover on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, mouseover

With Images

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vrFB.png

I just can do like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9djDt.png

code:

```
<img class="tooltip" title="HERE THE TOOLTOP" alt="" src="img.png">
```

And I can't put images on title=""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to look at the way you approach your information for this. If this is going to be inside the loop you have to include it in your template. I would look into using custom fields and meta-boxes to simplify the backend part.

If you're not too familiar doing this I would look into the http://www.advancedcustomfields.com plugin and within your template put a if statement that will display a div/img and position it. They have some documentation and I would learn the basics of if/else in php. Then I would use a simple mouseenter / mouseleave jquery event to show the hidden div or toggle.